# Unsetting Session the right way

Tags: php, session, unset

I was trying to pass an error message to another page using session variable. On the handler page, the session was initialized in the manner:

```
function sess() {
    $index = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['error'] = ($index == '') ? 'name cannot be empty' : $index . " is a good name";
    header("Location: http://website-name.com/form");
}; sess();
```

and on the other page is something like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['error']; unset($_SESSION['error']);
};
```

Now if the form is submitted with an empty field, the error `name cannot be empty` becomes the value of the session. After that, if the name is then set, the value of the session doesn't change but still returns `name cannot be empty`.

I've checked to see if it has something to do with the fact that the session was called within a function. got no idea! but found online a way to unset all variable using session_unset. But it's actually one session variable that i want to unset and i found something like `session_unset($_SESSION['error'])`. However, using it did not unset all session but the `$_SESSION['error']` doesn't get set anymore within the function unless i use the `unset($_SESSION['error'])` which doesn't terminate the first session that is set.

So what is actually going wrong? how does `unset_session()` works differently form `unset()`? what does it has to do with being inside a function? As far as i can recall, `$_SESSION[]` is a global variable just like `$GLOBALS[]` which can be access in any scope.

Comment: why not use a GET param to send the message? `header("Location: http://website-name.com/form?error=$msg");`
you can access the error by `echo $_GET['error'];`

Comment: I thought about that, but i decided to use session in order not to display more info after the `/form` so it simulate a single page request. However, going through this error has given me a reason not to divert back to using `$_GET[ ]` because if such error occurs again, i should be able to solve it.  I just tried something few minutes back. I commented `//header("Location: https://website-name.com/form/")`, and right before it, i added `echo $_SESSION['error']` and it displayed the value correctly. I wrote the same command outside the function and it did nothing.